# How to connect windows network drive using python code to Azure Function App which is having Linux environment

Tags: python, linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am having a use case where I need to list down the files from the Windows network drive but my code needs to be run in Azure Function App which will be a Linux environment.

Please let me know where I am having issues. Thanks in advance!

Please see below the code snippet

```
username = "************"
password = "************"
mkdirCmd = "/mnt/test/"
os.mkdir(mkdirCmd)
logging.info('directory created')
cmd="mount -t cifs -o username=%s,password=%s //<drive-path> /mnt/test" % (username, password)
logging.info('Executing command - %s ',cmd)
os.system(cmd)
logging.info('Network drive mounted')
arr = os.listdir('/mnt/test/')
```

I am getting an error as below -

arr = os.listdir('/mnt/gcam/')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/test/'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest listing the files from the directory and print them to check if you got the successful connection.

If that is successful, we need to add the correct parameters in the mount command.

As per the error message which you are getting looks like it is fetching in the wrong folder or there is no successful connection.

> mount -t cifs -o username=<win_share_user>,password=<win_share_password> //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share

If we can access the file system, then we can store/save the credentials in /etc/win-credentials as below:

```
username=user
password=password
domain=domain
```

then can pass as below:

> mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/win-credentials //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share